# ibatis to mybatis migration

Tags: syntax, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

ibatis conversion of `<isNotEmpty property="A"> is <if test='A != null and A != "" '>`

the above conversion works fine for string. But how to compare the list along with null check to check if the list is notEmpty

I tried following things

```
<if test='List != null and List.size() &gt; 0'>
<if test='List != null and List.isNotEmpty()'>(because isEmpty() worked fine)
<if test='List != null and !(List.isEmpty())'>
<if test='List != null and !List.isEmpty()'>
```

But if I use isEmpty() along with null check for alternative to isNotEmpty work fine, Im bit confused on this part

Any explanation on this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is [ONGL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html). Operands are java expression.

To achieve your purpose, the last seems to be the best:

```
<if test='List != null and !List.isEmpty()'>
```

Or null-safe util method such as:

```
<if test='org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(List)'>
```

Using class full qualified name is required to replace import statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the condition List is Empty or not in many ways in myBatis.

Choose the suitable answer from below which matches your requirement.

**Basic Check**

```
<if test="list != null and list.size()>0">
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
      open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</if>
```

If you are doing the same in some **SQL where statements** you can do the below.

```
WHERE 
    <choose>
        <when test="list==null || list.isEmpty()">
            1 = 0 <!-- a test returning false, to adapt depending on you DB vendor -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            ID IN <foreach item="item" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">#{item}</foreach>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
```

**Using Dynamic SQL**

```
WHERE <*condition1*>
<dynamic>
<isNotEmpty prepend="AND" property="list">
    yourTbl.pk_ID IN            
    <iterate property="list" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">                    
        #list[]#                    
    </iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
</dynamic>
```